# Gertting Error installing firebase cli in linux mint

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I use `crazi_boii@crazi-Boii ~ $ sudo npm install -g firebase-tools` to install the cli.
and the cmd get executed perfectly.

[this is the error i get after typing the command "firebase --version"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMyil.png)

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/tar/lib/pack.js:32
const EOF = Buffer.alloc(1024)
                   ^

TypeError: Buffer.alloc is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/tar/lib/pack.js:32:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/tar/lib/create.js:6:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
```

pls help. .
Thank you

Comment: Please don't show pictures of code and errors here.  It's far better to copy and paste the text into a code block so it's easier to read and search.

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: node version - v4.2.6 @DougStevenson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Functions for Firebase uses node 6, [as stated in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started).  You're using a much older version, so you'll need to upgrade your node installation.  If you don't want to use a package manager to force an upgrade for what you have now, you can install any version of node in your home directory using [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

Comment: I tried to install firebase while using node 12, had the `ERR! grpc@1.20.0 install: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`, used nvm to downgrade to node 11, now it's working !